# PySpark assigning name to column agg output

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

say I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
import pyspark.sql.types as sparktypes
import datetime

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="test")
sqlcontext = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)

rdd = sc.parallelize([('a',datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 9, 0, 0)),
                      ('b',datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 27, 0, 0)),
                      ('c',datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 31, 0, 0))])
testdf = sqlcontext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "date"])

print(testdf.show())
print(testdf.printSchema())
```

gives a test dataframe:

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|                date|
+---+--------------------+
|  a|2014-01-09 00:00:...|
|  b|2014-01-27 00:00:...|
|  c|2014-01-31 00:00:...|
+---+--------------------+


root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

And I want to get max of the date column:

```
max_date = testdf.agg(sf.max(sf.col('date'))).collect()
print(max_date)
```

gives:

```
[Row(max(date)=datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 31, 0, 0))]
```

how to apply custom name in the original operation itself to appear instead of automatically assigned `max(date)`,  say `max_date` so that i can access the value as `max_date[0]['max_date']` instead of `max_date[0][0]` or `max_date[0]['max(date)']`, also is there a better way of accessing this value, some attribute of Row()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
max_date = testdf.agg(sf.max(sf.col('date')).alias("newName")).collect()
```

As for a better way to access it. Not really. Collect brings a list of rows and you need to tell which column you need so you would go with:

```
max_date[0]['newName']
```

You can't get shorter than this...